# sharepoint 2010 customize new list form (list form web part) buttons

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I am working on a project that is using custom content types.  Changes are requested on a lot of these new list item forms.  I realize that I can customize the new form page, or edit the list form web part using designer or infopath, but I am not able to edit the buttons. I only have access to the field types and lables.

I need to move the buttons around and do some other customizations.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand what you'd like to do?

You can create a new item creation web part and add that to the new item form.
Is that what you'd like to do?

As far as I know, it is not possible to change the control layout of a field generated by sharepoint. You need to create one using visual studio.